# Virtual machine with separate desktop accounts

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, virtualbox, centos6.5

On our Centos-6.5 server, I want to install a temporary windows xp guest using virtual machines for windows applications. Thing is, I want to run the virtual machine in background and each windows user should be able to use remote desktop to connect to his/her windows account.

I tried VirtualBox and enabled the remote display and started the machine in headless mode. Problem is, all users see a single desktop with the remote display feature. In other words, if administrator logs in the windows account, then every user that connect to the IP:PORT with remote dsktop application will see the administrator's desktop.

Any way to fix that? Any alternative for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Windows XP shouldn't be used anymore for anything if you can help it at all. It's out of support for two years now.

About your real problem: Any desktop Windows (XP, 7, 8.1, 10) will only show one user for remote desktop. You need Windows Server with Terminal Services for what you want to do.

Comment: Do you mean, I have to install a Widnows Server as a guest? Is that enough? What are Terminal Services? Are they available in Windows Server? Or they are kind of third party applications? Can you explain more?

Comment: Yes, you would need Windows Server as the guest, instead of XP. Terminal services are a part of Windows Server (at least of some editions), but in most cases, you need additional CALs to use them. Licensing details are OT here though.